# Firebase reference object doesn't save to variable in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, swiftui

I'm storing data in Firebase and I've found a way to create an array of just the keys. The first print statement correctly prints out the array. However, outside of the database reference, the variable `listOfBannedNames` doesn't seem to save the array. The array prints out as [] with none of the keys inside. I would like to store the array in the variable listOfBannedNames to be used later.

```
    let username = username
    let formattedUsername = formatUsername(username: username)
    var listOfBannedNames = [String]()
    ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {
        snapshot in
        var bannedNamesList = [String]()
        for bannedNames in snapshot.children {
            bannedNamesList.append((bannedNames as AnyObject).key)
        }
        listOfBannedNames = bannedNamesList
        print(listOfBannedNames)
    })
    print(listOfBannedNames)
```

Comment: It is not clear the context, but it is about async behavior. Second print is called immediately after `observeSingleEvent` call, but not after it is finished (because this function quits immediately and request works in background). And definitely you have to make `listOfBannedNames` a property of owner.

Comment: There's a great answer by @Eduard. However, the bigger question is triggered by your comment *checks if the name inputed by the user is in the list of banned names* - if you want to check if the name the user entered is in that list, then why don't you just query Firebase for the name instead of loading in the entire list and processing it in code?

Comment: Could you direct me to where I could find out about doing that?

Comment: For sure. My concern is that as the list of banned names grows, it could be 10 million for example, it's a lot of overhead to load all of that to be processed. Much simpler to ask Firebase if there's a match. That process is called a query (or a filter) and is covered in [Filtering Data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/lists-of-data#filtering_data) section of the Getting Started Guide [Working With lists](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/lists-of-data). When responding to comments precede the name with an at sign, like @Jay. Then I'll be notified of your response.

Answer (score 2):

Thats exactly about async behavior. Try to make the following:

```
func makeRequestToFirebase(completion: @escaping ([String]) -> Void) {
    ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {
        snapshot in
        var bannedNamesList = [String]()
        for bannedNames in snapshot.children {
            bannedNamesList.append((bannedNames as AnyObject).key)
        }
        listOfBannedNames = bannedNamesList
        print(listOfBannedNames)
        completion(listOfBannedNames) // - that will wait until the list of names arrives
    })
}
```

Then use the function:

```
makeRequestToFirebase() { names in
    print(names)
    workWithNames(names)
}
```

Now you can use it however you want, for example:

```
func workWithNames(names: [String]) {
    for name in names {
        if name == "Alexander" {
            print("One more Alexander found")
        }
}
```

Also please learn more about [escaping closures in Swift](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjE0sjfh97rAhWvxIsKHZWjDdcQFjAEegQIAhAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmedium.com%2Fswiftcommmunity%2Fwhat-do-mean-escaping-and-nonescaping-closures-in-swift-d404d721f39d&usg=AOvVaw2EzKQVTZAMmrwJo6ykcZ17).

Comment: Thanks for the response. I still seem to be having an issue where I'm unable to reference `listOfBannedNames` outside of the `makeRequestToFirebase` as I want to use the list for an if-statement.

Comment: @kj15 no problem with that. I've extended my answer for you.

Comment: Is there a way I could return the array to another function?

Comment: @kj15 what do you mean?

Comment: In `ContentView`, there's a function call that checks if the name inputed by the user is in the list of banned names. That function then checks the name and returns a bool.